# how to rotate any shape continuously in D3 js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to call the update function to rotate the text by 1 degree and once the degree reaches 360 again the rotation angle becomes 0 and hence it will keep on rotating. But I think this is not the right way to approach the problem also it is not working. So suggest me the way to do it if anyone know it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var width = 600;
var height = 300;

var holder = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)    
  .attr("height", height); 

// draw the text
holder.append("text")
.style("fill", "black")
.style("font-size", "56px")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate(0)")
.text("Hi, how r u doing");

// Initial starting angle of the text

for(var i=0;i<=360;i++){
    update(i);
    if(i==360){i=0;}
}


var n;
// update the element
function update(n) {
// rotate the text
holder.select("text")
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate("+n+")");
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Example JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4k0yynej/).

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle with that?

Comment: You know that a for loop is executed hundreds of thousands of times per second, don't you?

Comment: Yes I know, that is why I am looking for some other method to do it. If you know then please tell me. @GerardoFurtado

Comment: For a solution independent of D3 or any other JS fiddling have a look at [*"How to do a webkit css endless rotation-animation."*](/q/6410730).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop never ends as you reset the counter `i` to 0 just before it finishes. If you remove this line, the code will have no visible result as the for loop executes so quickly, it's already completed before you can see anything.

A better solution is to use `setInterval` e.g.

```
var width = 600;
var height = 300;

var holder = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)    
  .attr("height", height); 

// draw the text
holder.append("text")
.style("fill", "black")
.style("font-size", "56px")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate(0)")
.text("Hi, how r u doing");

// Initial starting angle of the text

var i = 0;
var timeInterval = 10;
setInterval(function(){
        i += 1;
        update(i % 360) 
  },timeInterval);


var n;
// update the element
function update(n) {
// rotate the text
holder.select("text")
.attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate("+n+")");
}
```

You can control the speed by adjusting the `timeInterval` variable.

I've added an example JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sffcxede/1/).

Comment: Upvoted, but why are you using the modulo (`i℅360`)? It works just fine with `i` alone: 360, 720, 1080 etc are all the same angle.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Just a speculation here - to avoid overflowing the counter?

Comment: The counter never stops increasing (the counter is `i`, tot the value passed to function update).